# How to iterate through the top 3 posts from the last two weeks in liquid/jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Let me add some context: i'm trying to automate my boring reports to management using jekyll!

I'd like to write a post for every activity i do and, every week, ship the compiled report with the "top 3 highlights" from this week and from last week.

My shot at it, as a jekyll newbie, was adding the week of publishing and if that post is a highlight or not in the yaml front matter:

```
---
layout: event
title:  "Gave a Jelyll Talk!"
date:   2015-04-23 16:05:04
highlight: week
week: 17
---
```

And get the last two weeks in the template, like this:

```
---
layout: email
---

Here are my activities from the last two weeks:

{% assign hls = (site.posts | where: "highlight" , "week") %}
{% assign weeks = (hls | group_by: "week") %}
{% assign thisw = weeks[0] %}
{% assign lastw = weeks[1] %}

<h1>Week #{{thisw.name}}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for post in thisw.items %}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>

<h1>Week #{{lastw.name}}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for post in lastw.items %}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

That kinda works, but, i'd like to ask:

Is it possible to automatically calculate the current week, get only posts from the past two weeks (not future or prior), only the latest 3 highlights from each week and avoid repeating the html template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider writing a plugin for Jekyll, something like this:

`WeeklyHighlights.rb`

```
module Jekyll
    class WeeklyHighlights < Generator

        safe true
        priority :high

        def week_id(time)
            # to handle turn of year properly
            return time.strftime('%Y-%W')
        end

        def generate(site)
            # hash (dict) to store highlights grouped by week number
            highlights_by_week = {}

            today = Time.now
            # initialize recent weeks with empty highlights
            (0 .. 4).each do |i|
                w = week_id(today - i)
                highlights_by_week[w] = []
            end

            # group highlights according to week number
            site.posts.each do |post|
                if post['highlight'] != 'week'
                    next
                end
                week = week_id(post.date)
                highlights_by_week[week] ||= []
                highlights_by_week[week] << post
            end

            # make array of arrays of highlights, in the required order
            weekly_highlights = []
            highlights_by_week.keys.sort.reverse.each do |w|
                highlights_by_week[w].sort! {|a,b| b.date <=> a.date} # = hl.sort{|a,b| b.date <=> a.date }
                weekly_highlights << {'id' => w, 'hls' => highlights_by_week[w]}
            end

            # store prepared highlights
            site.config['weekly_highlights'] = weekly_highlights
        end
    end
end
```

Put the file in the plugins directory (typically `plugins` or `_plugins` in the root of Jekyll site), and then in the template:

```
{% for week in site.weekly_highlights limit:2 %}
<h2>week {{week.id}}</h2>
<ol>
{% for p in week.hls limit:3 %}
<li>{{p.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endfor %}
```

More on Jekyll plugins: [official documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/)

Comment: WOW, that is so awesome! Thanks a lot for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Yep... that should work.
At least you can get the current (i.e. build) time with `{{ site.time }}` and format it with a [liquid filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/additional-filters#date) to get the week number like so:

```
{% assign current_week = site.time | date: "%w" | plus: 0 %}
```

(You need to apply the `plus: 0` filter too, to get a number instead of a string assigned.) Now things get nasty, as you might want to consider turn of year properly... but it should be doable.

I can think of getting strings like `YEAR-WEEKNUMBER` for the last three weeks, assign all posts with same date string to a new variable, say `posts_lastweek` and so on. Then, loop over the posts, compare and limit the for loop (`{% for post in posts_lastweek | limit: 3 %}`) or work with counters to limit the output.

Let me know if that works for you...

Comment: the "plus" filter and "limit" parameter, with the link to the liquid docs helped a lot, thanks!!!